# How to send multiple data with ajax to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How to send multiple data as URL parameter to server side php script using only Javascript/Ajax.

**I don't need to use Jquer.y**

I am tying this way:

```
xhttp.open("GET", 'spec_crawler.php?value='+postValue+'&tablename='+tablename+'&id='+postProdID+'\'', true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send();
```

On server side I am getting only value:

```
$html_snippet =$_GET['value'];
```

Others are empty. but from client side I am sending the proper value.

Am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: That should work fine? You probably want to URL encode the variables though.

Comment: Uhm, maybe not, what's the `+'\''` at the end for, looks invalid, you can't end the URL like that after the querystring `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content type "**application/x-www-form-urlencoded**" is usually used for POST requests.
Encode each param value with `encodeURIComponent` function:

```
var params = 'value=' + encodeURIComponent(postValue) +'&tablename=' + encodeURIComponent(tablename) +'&id='+ encodeURIComponent(postProdID);
xhttp.open("GET", 'spec_crawler.php?' + params, true);          
xhttp.send();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Do i have to decode value on the server side? Actually the value is a large html source code. Please suggest

Comment: you don't need to decode URL-encoded string on server side. From PHP documentation: `Warning: The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded. Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have unexpected and dangerous results.
`

Comment: problem i am facing is encodeURIComponent(postValue) is not giving me any response from server if the postValue is the large html source code i need to send.
But when i am sending small string in postValue that works. I guess there is a problem with encodeURIComponent. Do you have any idea?

Comment: another thing it's working fine on my local pc. But not working on my linux server (my godaddy server)

Comment: you shouldn't pass a large html source code via GET params. Use POST request for those cases

Comment: "simply POST in replace of GET will work?" - No, replacing is not enough. For POST request you should set the proper header information along with the request such as: `http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");`

Comment: as for http `504` error: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/504error.htm